# Azure AD SSO without microsoft login page

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, adfs

I am newbie in Azure AD field and little bit confused.

We have an existing web application (app1) with a login page (app1/login) used for auth/authorization of users against AD. The requirement is to provide flexibility to users to navigate to application(app2) upon clicking on a link. This application is host by a different company and we would like to provide a seamless experience to user without having to login into app2 . we were provided with SAML metadata, relaystate URL & assertion consumer service URL by app2 team.

We have deployed the application in Azure Enterprise applications with Single sign on enabled. When we test using the validate button, we are able to see the partners page successfully.

We would like to implement this in code and we have tried the below approaches.

1. We were able to prepare a Deeplink with samlrequest & relaystate like https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenID/Samlrequest={request}&RelyaState={URL} But the relaystate url(redirect URL) only works if we are logged into azure portal. Can a access token be passed in the request to ? we are using microsoft graph REST API for auth of users and can grab the access token.
2. In Azure portal, under the enterprise application -> testapplication, there are properties and their is User Access URL( https://myapp.microsoft.com/sign/applicationID?TenantId=ID). If we are logged into azure portal, redirect works. If not, we are shown with microsoft login page. Can we get a access token and pass the token to User Access URL ?

Answer (score 1):

Why is the question tagged "ADFS". Are you using that?

The idea of Enterprise applications is that they appear on the myapps.microsoft.com page if you enable that feature.

So a user navigates to the myapps page, authenticates to Azure AD and then has access to all the applications.

The shortcut you mention is simply what happens when the user clicks that app. in the myapps page.

But you need to login to Azure AD first. If you are logging into your PC first, you should be able to achieve this using IWA.

Comment: We have used azure enterprise application SSO to test the vendor provided ADFS URL adfs/ls and it has worked. How can I do the same operation with code (web application).